# How to find running applications are in minimized state using java?

Tags: java, windows, jna

How to find all the running applications in windows desktop are in minimized state using java?

Answer (score 4):

You need to first [download](http://java.net/projects/jna/downloads/directory/3.2.7) **jna.jar** and **platform.jar** and add them to your classpath.  You can figure out the Windows system calls to make by looking at the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633516%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Here is the code to enumerate over all minimized windows:

```
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HWND;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinUser.WINDOWINFO;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinUser.WNDENUMPROC;

public class Minimized {
    private static final int MAX_TITLE_LENGTH = 1024;
    private static final int WS_ICONIC = 0x20000000;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        User32.EnumWindows(new WNDENUMPROC() {
            @Override
            public boolean callback(HWND arg0, Pointer arg1) {
                WINDOWINFO info = new WINDOWINFO();
                User32.GetWindowInfo(arg0, info);

                // print out the title of minimized (WS_ICONIC) windows
                if ((info.dwStyle & WS_ICONIC) == WS_ICONIC) {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[MAX_TITLE_LENGTH];
                    User32.GetWindowTextA(arg0, buffer, buffer.length);
                    String title = Native.toString(buffer);
                    System.out.println("Minimized window = " + title);
                }
                return true;
            }
        }, 0);
    }

    static class User32 {
        static { Native.register("user32"); }
        static native boolean EnumWindows(WNDENUMPROC wndenumproc, int lParam);
        static native void GetWindowTextA(HWND hWnd, byte[] buffer, int buflen);
        static native boolean GetWindowInfo(HWND hWnd, WINDOWINFO lpwndpl);
    }
}
```